# How to handle response varying from developer tool to code debugging in chrome?

Tags: java, chrome, rest-assured

I'm using RESTassured with Java. Getting response in compressed from UTF16 format. Response varies from developer tool to code debugging in Chrome/Firefox, here variation means some character got changed.

**Steps:**

1. Loaded the URL
2. Opened developer tool by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>
3. Selected the API and checked the response. Here i got response like: `ᯡࡈ䆼̀䬥堰攢䰢\ᙴঠ㙀ழⓒ`
4. Then gone to sources then checked the response it was something like this `ᯡࡈ䆼̀䬥堰攢䰢ᙴঠ㙀ழⓒ`

How to handle this? what all the response contains? is it contains headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by following:

```
String x=respe.asString();
        JSONParser par = new JSONParser(); 
        String  st = (String) par.parse(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you show is actually a **response body**. Headers are represented in "Headers" tab in Dev Tools like this:

[image]

Brief look up of what you provided shows that it's UTF-16 encoded string:

[image]

**For example:**

1 - [BATAK LETTER CA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1be1/index.htm)

2 - [MANDAIC LETTER ATT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0848/browsertest.htm)

3 - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/41bc/browsertest.htm no dedicated name

Answer (score 0):

I guess the trivial way to handle this is convert the charset to unicode and verify. Java String supports unicode by-default.

The below article states how to convert to and from unicode charset:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/unicode.html

Coming to the second part of the question. Below are the major part of an HTTP Response.

- Status
- Response Header
- Response Fields

Below is the link which details out http Response:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html